# Unable to ignore import in jest

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I want to ignore below code when I'm doing unit testing using jest.

```
import Context from 'folder/Context';
```

this is having ts extension.

Context.ts contains ---- >

```
import {createContext} from 'react'
const Context = createContext({})
export const Provider = context.Provider
export default Context;
```

Now how to ignore this import in jest config.

Tried below options but it's not working.

```
 "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
        "<rootDir>/src/folder/Context.ts"
      ],
      "testPathIgnorePatterns":[ "<rootDir>/src/folder/Context.ts"]
```

but it's not working. Please guide me here to proceed further.

Comment: Why do you want to ignore that code?

Comment: jest not able to find that module and throws can not find module error, is there a way to mock that import or ignore that import ??

Comment: This is XY problem. If it's unable to find the module while it exists, consider starting with fixing it. This is what TS config `paths` are for and they are probably used in production confg.

Comment: Estus Flask - so if I add proper values in tsconfig would. it fix for jest ?